# It is really tedious to write a bunch of data classes for parsing a simple JSON using Kotlin's seriallization library. Any better way?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization, json-deserialization

I tried parsing JSON using Kotlin's default serialization library. However, I found it really overwhelming to write a bunch of data classes to deserialize a simple JSON string.

To illustrate,

```
{
  "artists": {
    "items": [
      {
        "genres": [
          "desi pop",
          "filmi",
          "modern bollywood"
        ],
        "images": [
          {
            "url": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab6761610000e5ebb2b70762d89a9d76c772b3b6"
          }
        ],
        "name": "Arijit Singh",
        "type": "artist"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

for this data, I had to write these many classes,

```
@Serializable
data class Root(val artists: SubRoot)

@Serializable
data class SubRoot(val items: List<Artist>)

@Serializable
data class Artist(
    val genres: List<String>,
    val images: List<Image>,
    val name: String,
    val type: String
)

@Serializable
data class Image(val url: String)
```

Does anybody know a better way? Some library with in-built magic that does these kind of stuff for me?

Comment: You could just use `Map`. Although that’s then not typesafe and the code is ugly. Or you could use a generator - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-; but in my experience you still need to do some manual tweaking to get the types right, parse dates etc etc.

Comment: Alternatively switch to a language with weaker types - like Groovy (or JavaScript or Python) if you think you’re not benefitting from the type system.

Comment: There are a bunch of Java-libraries regarding Json, but as @BoristheSpider has stated, then you usually lose type safety, because you then really just get nested map&array like structures. This can be okay, if the structure never changes, but if an interface changes, you might accidentally handle bad data without noticing.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the automatic mapping you can just parse them as JsonElements and do your own thing instead of letting the library map them to those data classes.

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#json-elements

For example, if you want to get that url, you could do:

```
val root = Json.parseToJsonElement(json)
return root.
    jsonObject["artists"]?.
    jsonObject?.get("items")?.
    jsonArray?.get(0)?.
    jsonObject?.get("images")?.
    jsonArray?.get(0)?.
    jsonObject?.get("url")?.
    jsonPrimitive.toString()
)
```

This specific example will return null if any field couldn't be found while traversing the tree. It will give an IllegalArgumentException if any of the casts fail.